# I/O problem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io

I want to learn about data input with keyboard. Please help me and introduce me some resources.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain where you are coming from?  Input from the keyboard how?  In Ruby, or Ruby on Rails (i.e. a web-server)?  Have you attempted this problem at all already?

Comment: @ghayes: Has he even mentioned Ruby on Rails anywhere in his question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Readline`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/readline/rdoc/classes/Readline.html) class.